# startDrag method Deprecated and unable to compile the program

Tags: java, android, deprecated

`startDrag(android.content.ClipData, android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder, java.lang.Object, int)` is deprecated. How to solve this without losing compatibility to the older versions? Are there any alternatives? I'm learning android basics and while trying out a simple drag and drop exercise, I encountered this error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to Androids API reference [`startDrag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startDrag(android.content.ClipData,%20android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)) was deprecated in API level 24

Use [`startDragAndDrop()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startDragAndDrop(android.content.ClipData,%20android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)) for newer platform versions.

And since Android API level 24 equals Android N you can use:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    view.startDragAndDrop(...);
} else {
    view.startDrag(...);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`startDrag` was very recently deprecated - in API 24. So you could use `startDragAndDrop` instead and differentiate between versions.

What you could also say is *preserving compatibility to lower versions*. The thing is Drag&Drop was introduced in API 11. So you could try differentiating between versions:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    //MyDragEventListener comes in here
}
```

Otherwise as said, there is no official Drag&Drop for < API 11. There is not much use of implementing it for Android below API 14 (or API 15 for that matter), because per Android Studio, there are only a handful of devices running below that version, i.e. only mere 2.3%.

If you still, insist on doing it, you could use a third party library such as Android-DragArea.

Hope this helps!