# Drag and Drop: startDrag deprecated

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I tried the accepted solution here: [startDrag method Deprecated and unable to compile the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596889/startdrag-method-deprecated-and-unable-to-compile-the-program)

So:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     view.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
 } else {
     view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
 }
```

But "startDrag" is crossed out and I have an error saying that it is deprecated, which means I can't compile.

I looked here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

But the example they give is the deprecated solution:

```
  v.startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
              myShadow,  // the drag shadow builder
              null,      // no need to use local data
              0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
  );
```

So what can I use?

Comment: Actually, you can compile deprecated functions try to press the run button

Comment: deprecated means that this function will be left as is even if there is a bug and there is currently a better alternative that will be updated regularly if it has problems.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I try to run it, I get this weird error: Error:(170, 14) error: illegal character: '\ufeff'

Comment: Can you show me the line it crashes in it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211589/error1-1illegalcharacter-ufeff-when-compiling-on-android-studio

Comment: It's the last curly bracket. Ok, thanks for the link. I'll try and work it out, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can compile deprecated functions try to press the run button.

Deprecated means that this function will be left as is even if there is a bug and there is currently a better alternative that will be updated regularly if it has problems.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211589/error1-1illegalcharacter-ufeff-when-compiling-on-android-studio) is a question about your error.